# ¿Por qué me arroja error cuando deseo mostrar el método del objeto por pantalla con los datos que le he ido introduciendo en el array?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto, javascript-metodo

Tengo un método denominado info() perteneciente al objeto Frutas el cual deseo mostrar por pantalla con los datos que le he puesto en el array que he ido llenando pero al querer hacerlo me salta un error por la consola donde javascript me dice que el mismo no es una función. Aún cuando le coloqué los parámetros, salta este error, pero no sé si es que los parámetros debo pasárselos de una manera distinta por estar dentro de un array.

```
"use strict";
const frutas = []
class Fruta {
    constructor(producto, cantidad, precio) {
        this.producto = producto
        this.cantidad = cantidad
        this.precio = precio
    }
    info() {
        return `De ${this.producto} tenemos ${this.cantidad} y el valor es de $${this.precio}x kg`
    }
}

while (frutas.length < 2) {
    let producto = prompt("Ingrese el nombre del producto").toLowerCase()
    let cantidad = prompt("Ingrese la cantidad del stock")
    let precio = prompt("ingrese el valor del producto")
    if (!isNaN(cantidad) && !isNaN(precio)) {
        frutas.push(new Fruta(producto, cantidad, precio))
    }
}

const mostrarInventario = () =>{
    console.log(frutas)
}

mostrarInventario()

document.write(frutas.info(frutas.producto, frutas.cantidad, frutas.precio));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es simple, `frutas` no es un elemento de tipo fruta, es un array, por lo que es obvio que no contiene ningún método llamado info.

Para llamar al método info para cada elemento del array, simplemente itera en el array.

```js
const frutas = []
    class Fruta {
      constructor(producto, cantidad, precio) {
        this.producto = producto
        this.cantidad = cantidad
        this.precio = precio
      }
      info() {
        return `De ${this.producto} tenemos ${this.cantidad} y el valor es de $${this.precio}x kg`
      }
    }

    while (frutas.length < 2) {
      let producto = prompt('Ingrese el nombre del producto').toLowerCase()
      let cantidad = prompt('Ingrese la cantidad del stock')
      let precio = prompt('ingrese el valor del producto')
      if (!isNaN(cantidad) && !isNaN(precio)) {
        frutas.push(new Fruta(producto, cantidad, precio))
      }
    }

    const mostrarInventario = () => {
      console.log(frutas)
    }

    mostrarInventario()
    frutas.forEach((fruta) => {
      const product = document.createElement('div')
      product.innerHTML = fruta.info()
      document.body.appendChild(product)
    })
```